# Creating Users from a text file using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I've been looking at some of the other answers for this question but it hasn't solved my issue.

Basically, I need to create a script that reads from a text file, that is given by a user input, and creates users from the contents of the file. I've managed to get it to create the first user but it doesn't seem to be creating the other users in the file.

My text document is literally:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

And heres the code I have:
`echo -n "Enter name of text file "; read text
while read USER;
      do
      USERNAME=$(cut -d$'\n' -f $text)
      echo $USERNAME
      useradd -m "${USERNAME}"
      done < $text`

It seems to only be reading the very first entry in the text file but I thought using the \n would mean it cut the other lines and use them next? I tried using the 'cat' command instead but wasn't having much luck with it and this is the furthest I've managed to get but I was hoping someone would help me find where I've gone wrong. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Why not just `xargs -n 1 useradd -m <file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should start your script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

to ensure that it is interpreted as bash.

Second, the value you need is already available in the `USER` variable. There is no need to use `cut`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "Enter name of text file: "; read FILENAME
while read USER; do
    echo "$USER"
    useradd -m "${USER}"
done < "${FILENAME}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this method worked. I was stuck on that for longer than I should have been but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to print and pipe to shell

```
$ awk '{print "useradd -m "$1}' <file> | sh
```